# How to solve AppRegistry.registerComponent Error in React Native

Tags: android, ios, facebook, react-native

Just started Exploring React Native but unfortunately, I am stuck with this error

**App(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may
 have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object**

I have tried checking and taking reference with other question but did not able to figure it out. Kindly check the attached screen shot - 
[image: Simulator Screen Shot]
Here is how my index.ios looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/Header';
import AlbumList from './src/components/AlbumList';

//Create a Component
const App = () => {
   <View>
     <Header headerText={'Albums'} />;
     <AlbumList />
   </View>;
};

//Render it to the device
AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

Any suggestion will be really helpfull

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a return in the `App` function:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
   <View>
     <Header headerText={'Albums'} />;
     <AlbumList />
   </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: getting this error @RRikesh - Rawtext ";" must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> component